# Smoothness of Artin Stack by Dimension Estimation

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-stacks

For a proper scheme or, more general, a Deligne-Mumford stack $X$ over an algebraically closed field $k$ it is known that if at all points $x$ the dimension $dim_x X$ of the local ring at that point is equal to the dimension of the tangent space $T_x X$, then the scheme is smooth.

Does this somehow generalize to Artin stacks after replacing the tangent space by the tangent complex?

Comment: What is your field? The first statement is incorrect for non-perfect fields. Otherwise, you should be writing ‘regular’ and not ‘smooth’.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, as I usually work over algebraic closed fields only, I was inaccurate in that point.